# Cardinality of "almost coinciding families"

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let's call $\textit{almost coinciding family}$ a family $\mathcal{D} \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ such that for every two $A, B \in \mathcal{D}$ we have $\vert A  \Delta B \vert < \omega $ (meaning that the symmetric difference is finite.

Can we, similarly to the case of $\textit{almost disjoint families}$, find such a family of the cardinality of the continuum?

Comment: How many finite subsets does $\omega$ have?

Answer (score 0):

(i). Let $D$ be a non-empty almost-coinciding fsmily.Let $A\in D$. For any $B\in D$ let $f(B)=(A\setminus B\,,\,B\setminus A).$ Then $f$ is injective from $D$ into the countable set $[\omega]^{<\omega}\times [\omega]^{<\omega}.$

(ii). Let $f:\omega\to\Bbb Q$ be a bijection. For each $r\in\Bbb R$ let $(r_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of rationals converging to $r$, and let $g(r)=\{m\in\omega :f(m)\in\{r_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\}.$ Then $g$ is injective from $\Bbb R$ into $[\omega]^{\omega}.$ And $\{g(r):r\in\Bbb R\}$ is an almost-disjoint family.

Comment: Once you've fixed $A$, the symmetric difference with $B$ determines it uniquely. So the map $f(B)=A\mathop{\triangle}B$ is enough.

Comment: The second question was not asking to find an almost disjoint family of size continuum. Instead it asked if we can find an "almost coinciding family" of size continuum.